# How to update the value on notes entity using a custom field?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to update the data on notes entity using a custom date field.

So, tried with the below options :

1. Tried creating the custom date field on notes entity. But OOB, we cannot create custom fields on notes entity.
2. Tried to create the relationship between the custom entity and notes entity, but CRM doesn't support this as well.

Please let me know the suggestions for updating the data on notes entity using the custom field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that it is impossible to customize the Annotation entity with a custom field or custom relationship.

You could create a custom entity (perhaps called Note Header) designed to store metadata such as one or more dates about the note and enable it for Notes (under the Communication and Collaboration section on the entity create form).

You could relate the Note Header entity to other entities. The idea would be that each Note Header would allow only a single Note... If necessary you could write a plugin to enforce this.

Admittedly this is a bit convoluted. If a simple date is all you need to add to a Note, perhaps think about concatenating the date to the subject (Title) field.